# how to get laravel to get back to the profile page after follow/unfollow happens

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a social network website and one of the functions is followed and unfollow that get you to follow/unfollow another user on the website, I want to know how to make Laravel go back to the profile page after the follow or unfollow happened, is there is a way that I can redirect to the profile controller with the id of the user I just follow/unfollow because that is what the profile controller requires to get the data of the user.

**The Following Controller**

```
    public function following(Request $request) {
        $follower=followers::create([
            'id'=>Auth::id(),
            'follower_id'=>$request->input('user_id'),
        ]);
        return back();
    }
    public function unfollowing(Request $request) {
        $u=DB::table('followers')->where('id',auth()->id())->where('follower_id',$request->input('user_id'),)->delete();
        return back();
    }
```

**Get Profile Controller**

```
    public function get_all_data(Request $request) {
        $id=$request->input('user_id');

        $userdata=DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name','last_name','profile_img','cover_img')
            ->where('id',$id)->first();
        $is_exist=false;
        $user=DB::table('followers')->where('follower_id',$id)->where('id',auth()->id())->get();
        if(count($user)==1){$is_exist=true;}
        if($id!=auth()->id()) {
            return view('show-prof')->with(compact('userdata','is_exist'));
        }
        else {
            return view('profile');
        }
```

**web.php**

```
    Route::post('get-profile',  ['as' => 'get-profile', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\showprofile@get_all_data'])->middleware('auth');
Route::post('follow', [App\Http\Controllers\follow::class, 'following'])->name('follow');
    Route::post('unfollow', [App\Http\Controllers\follow::class, 'unfollowing'])->name('unfollow');
```

**TLDR:-**
I want to get back to the profile page of the user I just follow or unfollow

Comment: `return redirect("/profile")` ?

Comment: ok, I used wildcard {id} to get to user profile instead of post and now its working fine, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to do it with laravel but one the best is:

```
  return redirect('/profile/{id}');
```

you can use Laravel wildcard